# What path should I install files to?

Tags: installation, 13.04, eclipse, netbeans

I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find an answer... I've just switched from windows and am trying to get the hang of ubuntu 13.04. I just installed JDK7u40 with netbeans 7.3.1 but it defaulted to the home folder... I don't think this was right since all my other apps that were installed through software centre went somewhere else and it doesn't show up when I search using the superkey.

So where should/can I set the install path next time to better my allocation? For example, when I manually install eclipse android sdk, can I set the install path to "/usr/share"?

Help is most appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what "better my allocation" is, but you can install that kind of stuff whereever you want, as long as you know where it is. Home folder is ok, in case you are the only one to use it. Creating your own foldes (allocations?) is ok too.

Answer (score 1):

When I install software, I tend to do 1 of 2 things:

1. If the software is via a deb file, I just let it install where it defaults to.
2. If it's not, I tend to install stuff to the `/opt/` dir (requires sudo-er privileges) and then add an `appname.application` file to `/usr/share/applications` so it shows up in dash.

Comment: Cool, you understood exactly what I wanted. I looked up how to create the application file and found this;
http://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2013/05/15/ubuntu-13-04-adding-launchers-to-unity-panel/

Comment: For some reason netbeans is now in the dash when I search it even though I don't remember doing anything with it... I will test this method out when I instead the eclipse adt and report back. Thanks a lot this helped tremendously!

Comment: I would also reference [https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/installation-guide/powerpc/directory-tree.html] for the choice of installation directories.  Typically, I do /usr for applications specific to one user's login, otherwise it's /opt if every user should use the app.